# Angular material datepicker component not working

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am learning angularjs and using angularjs material datepicker component for date control but its not working, I am using the same code as found in material.angularjs.org but my control is not showing please help.
My html page is DatePicker.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-aria.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-material.min.js"></script>

        <script src="myapp.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
            <md-content>
                <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
                <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
                <h4>Disabled date-picker</h4>
                <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" placeholder="Enter date" disabled></md-datepicker>
                <h4>Date-picker with min date and max date</h4>
                <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" placeholder="Enter date" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

myapp.js

```
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myDate = new Date();
    $scope.minDate = new Date(
        $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
        $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
        $scope.myDate.getDate());
    $scope.maxDate = new Date(
        $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
        $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
        $scope.myDate.getDate());
});
```

above is the code which I got from the site's documentation.
But its not working, what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Did you check the debug console for errors?

Comment: @Michelem - There is no error, my page is opening but it only showing the label not the controls

Comment: I had a similar problem, but funny enough I realized I am using version 0.10.1 and datepicker has been introduced lately with the version 0.11.0

Comment: In there month year picker available in this type of date picker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must have something wrong with your imports I think, I put you code in to [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XsMuvoo1tv8A0hViVdRJ?p=preview)

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <md-content>
      <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      <h4>Disabled date-picker</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" placeholder="Enter date" disabled></md-datepicker>
      <h4>Date-picker with min date and max date</h4>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" placeholder="Enter date"
                 md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"></md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

and it's working fine ?! Please check you imports!

Comment: What was the problem actually? What solved it exactly?

Comment: links to css and js files were dead, fixed !

Comment: @macrog can you please post the css and js links that are working? As I have be trying to use the given links (in demo) and they don't work within the hot towel angular application.

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention the following in your app.module.ts

```
import { MdDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { MdNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and this is in imports array

```
imports [
  MdDatepickerModule,
  MdNativeDateModule
]
```